# What difference between running program from ide and jar file

Tags: java, jar, runtime

All the good time.
I am beginner to java.
Wrote subtitle translator (for myself). In process it create two files: first is the file with translations, where to each English word puts translated word, second is local dictionary. In first file pair words are in different lines, but the beginning of word are aligned relative to each other due to the arrangement of spaces.

**Issue**:
When I compile and run from IDE (no matter Idea or Eclipse) program executed as I expected, however then I pack project into JAR file and run it, program disposes spaces on file incorrectly.

Use JDK 1.8 Idea community or Eclipse
How can it be?
If it helps, this is link to the project - https://github.com/Eramedy/TranslateSRT.git

Comment: What do you mean by "spaces are disposed incorrectly"? Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: It might probably help to show us some screenshots/output for both cases.

Comment: Thank you for your desire to help. In this [archive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-uEqFcGw69mY3pBeWhhT2xib0U/view?usp=sharing) you will find 3 files (each one in txt and png). Test.srt is a source file. Test(en-ru).srt a file that is crated then program is run from IDE, this is correct file. And last Test(en-ru)(1).srt was created when program run from jar, it placed a lot extra spaces.